# Redux onClick action not firing from Component, no errors or console errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an eCommerce React app I'm putting together that has a view of items. Each item has an *Add to cart* button with an onClick function that dispatches an *ADD_ITEM* action to update the cart in state.

The problem I'm seeing is that the Action is never firing and the state is never updating, but there aren't any console errors or anything to point me in the direction of what's broken.

I've looked at everything over and over, there's no typos and everything is connected to the store so I'm really at a loss as to why it's not working.

`Cart Reducer`

```
import { AnyAction } from "redux";
import CartActionTypes from "./cart.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: [],
};

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: AnyAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        hidden: !state.hidden,
      };
    case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

`Cart Actions`

```
import CartActionTypes from "./cart.types";

export const toggleCartHidden = () => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN,
});

export const addItem = (item) => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM,
  payload: item,
});
```

`Cart Types`

```
const CartActionTypes = {
  TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN: "TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN",
  ADD_ITEM: "ADD_ITEM",
};

export default CartActionTypes;
```

`Root Reducer`

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import userReducer from "./user/user.reducer";
import cartReducer from "./cart/cart.reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});
```

`Item Component with onClick/mapDispatchToProps function`

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addItem } from "../../redux/cart/cart.actions";
import { Item } from "../../pages/shop/shop.component";

const CollectionItem = ({ item }: { item: Item }) => {
  const { name, price, imageUrl } = item;

  return (
    <CollectionItemContainer>
      <Image
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}
        className="image"
      />
      <CollectionFooter>
        <Name>{name}</Name>
        <Price>{price}</Price>
      </CollectionFooter>
      <CollectionItemButton
        onClick={() => addItem(item)}
        className="custom-button inverted"
      >
        Add to cart
      </CollectionItemButton>
    </CollectionItemContainer>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addItem: (item) => dispatch(addItem(item)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CollectionItem);
```

`Item Collection component (Parent of Item Component)`

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Item } from "../../pages/shop/shop.component";
import CollectionItem from "../collection-item/collection-item.component";

const CollectionPreview = ({
  title,
  items,
}: {
  title: string;
  items: Array<Item>;
}) => {
  return (
    <CollectionPreviewContainer>
      <Title>{title.toUpperCase()}</Title>
      <Preview>
        {items
          .filter((item, idx) => idx < 4)
          .map((item) => (
            <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
          ))}
      </Preview>
    </CollectionPreviewContainer>
  );
};

export default CollectionPreview;
```

Comment: can try doing this    `onClick={() =>console.log(item)}` just want to see if anything logs

Comment: Yeah it's logging correctly with the output being ```{id: 3, name: "Cowboy Hat", imageUrl: "https://image.co/QdJwgmp/cowboy.png", price: 35}``` which leads me to believe it's something with my Redux setup but I'm not sure what

Comment: Do you have your app component wrapped like this or something along the lines like this ? `<Provider store={store}> <App/> </Provider>`

Comment: @BARNOWL Yeup that's exactly the setup

Comment: @Josh Props to you for this very well formatted question with all the context one could ask for!

Comment: @Leo absolutely, thank YOU for the in depth explanation and full context for why this was broken!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a very small issue, but very relevant issue in your code: In your `CollectionItem` component your not using the `addItem` function from your props, which was injected by `connect` with your `mapDispatchToProps` function. You probably meant to destructure it in the function definition of your `CollectionItem` component but just forgot it.

changing

```js
const CollectionItem = ({ item }: { item: Item }) =>
```

to

```js
const CollectionItem = ({ item, addItem }: { item: Item, addItem: () => void }) =>
```

should fix the issue.

Note that you didn't see any error because your action creator is called `addItem` too. Therefore when you call `addItem` in the `onClick` function, the function is still defined even though you didn't destructure it from the props. However calling the action creator instead of the function from `mapDispatchToProps` will just create the action (a plain js object) and return it, without dispatching it...

To avoid such hard to spot mistakes I would recommend to name the function injected through `mapDispatchToProps` differently than the action creator.

Example:

```js
const CollectionItem = ({ item /* missing fn here */ }: { item: Item }) => {
  const { name, price, imageUrl } = item;

  return (
    <CollectionItemContainer>
      <Image
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` }}
        className="image"
      />
      <CollectionFooter>
        <Name>{name}</Name>
        <Price>{price}</Price>
      </CollectionFooter>
      <CollectionItemButton
        onClick={() => handleAddItem(item)}
        className="custom-button inverted"
      >
        Add to cart
      </CollectionItemButton>
    </CollectionItemContainer>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  handleAddItem: (item) => dispatch(addItem(item)),
});
```

Not the the error would become really obvious, because a `handleAddItem` function not defined error would be thrown and you'd immediately know that you are missing the `handleAddItem` function in the first line of this example.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react'
import "./login.css"
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import  { auth, provider} from "./firebase";
function login() {
    const signin= () =>
    {
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider).catch(error => alert(error.message));
    };
    return (
        <div id="Login">
          
            <div id="login_logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/discord-logo-color-wordmark-1.svg"/>

            </div>
            <Button onClick={() => signin} >Sign in</Button>      
        </div>
    )
}

export default login;
```